# PHP - что за кодировка у json?

Tags: php

Не могу разобраться как привести в обычный текст. Имею результат в виде строки json, вот кусок. Через декодирование у меня его не получается привести в читаемый вид.

```
string(8533) ""{\"text_unique\":\"0.00\",\"result_json\":\"{\\\"date_check\\\":\\\"03.01.2020 20:12:39\\\",\\\"unique\\\":0,\\\"clear_text\\\":\\\"\\\\u041a\\\\u0435\\\\u0440\\\\u0430\\\\u043c\\\\u0438\\\\u0447\\\\u0435\\\\u0441\\\\u043a\\\\u0438\\\\u0439 \\\\u043a\\\\u0438\\\\u0440\\\\u043f\\\\u0438\\\\u0447 \\\\u0438\\\\u0437\\\\u0433\\\\u043e\\\\u0442\\\\u043e\\\\u0432\\\\u043b\\\\u0435\\\\u043d \\\\u0438\\\\u0437 \\\\u044d\\\\u043a\\\\u043e\\\\u043b\\\\u043e\\\\u0433\\\\u0438\\\\u0447\\\\u0435\\\\u0441\\\\u043a\\\\u0438 \\\\u0447\\\\u0438\\\\u0441\\\\u0442\\\\u043e\\\\u0433\\\\u043e \\\\u043d\\\\u0430\\\\u0442\\\\u0443\\\\u0440\\\\u0430\\\\u043b\\\\u044c\\\\u043d\\\\u043e\\\\u0433\\\\u043e \\\\u0441\\\\u044b\\\\u0440\\\\u044c\\\\u044f \\\\u043e\\\
```

Comment: Надо убрать лишние \ Тогда всё будет кодироваться отлично.

Comment: Это unicode правда с лишними слэшами как и сказал Denis640kb в комментарии выше.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кодировка: **CP1361**, постфильтр: **unicode-points**.

Декодирование:

```
{"text_unique":"0.00","result_json":"{"date_check":"03.01.2020 20:12:39","unique":0,"clear_text":"Керамический кирпич изготовлен из экологически чистого натурального сырья ... "}}
```